# How to provide sliding animation on visibility change for any control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to provide the animation for stack-panel on its visibility change. 
The Paint 3D of windows 10 provide the slide in animation for navigation view on menu button click. I want to do the same sliding effect to stack-panel on its visibility changed.
I tried the animation using the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations with following code

```
          <animations:Implicit.ShowAnimations>
            <animations:TranslationAnimation  Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1">
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.2" Value="0.6"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.4" Value="0.3"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.6" Value="0.8"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.8" Value="0.5"/>
            </animations:TranslationAnimation>
        </animations:Implicit.ShowAnimations>

        <animations:Implicit.HideAnimations>
            <animations:OpacityAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="1" To="0">
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.2" Value="0.5"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.4" Value="0.8"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.6" Value="0.3"/>
                <animations:ScalarKeyFrame Key="0.8" Value="0.6"/>
            </animations:OpacityAnimation>
        </animations:Implicit.HideAnimations>
```

But this just make the stack-panel fade in and fade out, where I want to slide it from left to right.

Comment: Hi Raghva, what have you tried already? Perhaps if you take the [tour] and read up on how to ask a question...

Comment: have you tried creating a storyboard using VS blend ? it is very easy to use and supports complex animations as well .

Comment: No I am not tried with storyboard, as I don't know anything about it. If you know any best place where I can see about the Storyboard?

Comment: Translation animations use Vector3KeyFrames, not ScalarKeyFrames. You won't be able to as easily achieve automatic visibility changes with Storyboards - staying with composition is the better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple items in inside one `<animations:Implicit.ShowAnimations>` element, so you can add both the `Translation` and `Opacity` animation there.

Also, translation uses absolute values, so what you are doing is moving the panel just one pixel to the right currently, which is imperceptible. Try setting `From="-200"` and `To="0"` for example.